# Getting first element of Observer Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuejs2

[image]

Hi dear friends, i cannot get first element or data etc. I did try notes[0] but the result was 'undefined'. What kind of array is this? First time i've seen and i am using Vue.Js

Comment: i think this is an async operation. do u use rxjs or promises ?

Comment: I manage datas with Vuex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the first element simply using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```
Array.from(notes)[0]
```

Also, `{__ob__: Observer}` is a special property added by Vue, it's part of the Reactivity system which allows Vue to track data changes and react to them.

More info about [Reactivity](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html)

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer.